# Why is firebase firestore performing multiple read operations if I limit it in the query?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in Kotlin where I check the last document of my collection after I ordered it by 'columnA':

```
db.collection("collection1").orderBy("columnA", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(1).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                       // Some operations
                    }
                }
```

As far as I know, Cloud Firestore should perform a single read when executing that operation. Is it right? So, why could Firestore be performing more than 30 read operations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480251/why-i-get-so-much-reads-in-firebasestore-flutter-chat-app check this

Comment: In my case I do not have any for statement...

Comment: How do you determine that "Firestore [is] performing more than 30 read operations"? If you do this in the Firebase console, keep in mind that having Firestore open in the console will also read the documents it shows, and these are charged reads too. This is the most common cause of additional reads for developers who are new to Firestore.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand it very well. You say that if I have the Firestore console opened it performs additional reading operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know, firebase should perform a single read when executing that operation. Is it right?

Yes, it is right. If you limit your query to return only a single element, you'll always be billed with only **one** read operation. According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), it is said:

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of **one document read** for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

So there will be also a cost of one read operation when you execute a query, even if the query yields no documents.

However, those extra read operations most likely might come if you leave the Firebase Console open, as the console is considered as any other client. Or, you perform other queries, that incur read operations from other parts of your code, that you are not aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I do not have any other reading operation after that query, so I still do not understand what is happening...

Comment: Try the following. Get the latest number of read operations. Don't perform any query. Close the Firebase Console, wait a few minutes, perform the query with the limit() call, refresh the Console. You should be able to see, only one new read operation. I've done that a hundred times and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, you can contact the Firebase team, but most likely is something that you are missing out. Firebase console, a query that you don't know about, that is performed before or after the one with the limitation.

Comment: Hey, jartymcfly! Have you solved the issue? Is there everything alright?

Comment: No, I don't solve it. Does Firestore perform some reading operations when console is opened, or something like that? I have the console opened to check the readings, and I am registering more reads than I theoretically should...

Comment: Yes, it does.  If something changes in your DB, while the console is open, you'll be billed with those read operations. This is what I tried to explain in my answer. Does this now explain those extra reads?